# Jupyterhub Notebook doesn't recognize Python modules

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to run Jupyterhub on a Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I've successfully done this before on a similar Amazon EC2 instance, but for some reason it's not cooperating with me here.

I've installed both the Python 27 and Python 35 Anaconda packages, so I expect to be able to access libraries like `matplotlib` and `numpy`.

When I use Python from the command line, I can successfully import `matplotlib`:

```
$ python3
>>> import matplotlib
>>> # no error
```

However, when I try and import `matplotlib` from an iPython notebook inside of Jupyterhub, I'm told no such module exists:

```
import matplotlib
-----------------------
ImportError
...
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Why does Jupyterhub not recognize the module despite my being able to use it through other means?

Comment: Is the notebook's kernel the same version as the default Python from your command line?

Comment: @nitind The notebook says "Python 3" kernel. The example holds true if I substitute `python` with `python3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself. I needed to specify a different Python instance in a generated `kernel.json` file.

To generate the `kernel.json` file:

```
sudo anaconda3/bin/ipython kernel install
```

Then edit it:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json

...

{
    "argv": [
        "/PATH/TO/ANACONDA/bin/python",
```